# El promedio de todos los números múltiplos de 9 que se encuentran entre el 290 y 2200

Tags: c#

Hola estoy aprendiendo en la programacion y tengo muchos problemas en la realización de este ejercicio, si alguien me pudiese ayudar, seria de gran ayuda.

```
using System;


namespace Ejercicio3
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            int numero;
            Console.Write("Ingresar numero: ");
            numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Promedio de los numeros " + numero + "numeros multiplos de 9: " + (((numero * numero * 9) + (numero * 9)) /2) / numero);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: te faltaria crear un array de numeros, un ciclo while o for para recorrer ese array e ir llenandolo con lo que ingresas por consola.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual es el problema que tenes?

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no se mucho del lenguaje, pero seguro si o si debes usar el operador resto % para encontrar la solución de los múltiplos de 9, despues un ciclo for, que recorra los el intervalo de los numeros, y por ultimo sacas el promedio, espero haberte podido ayudar